# Copy SQL Server table into a txt file before delete it from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, copy

I have a stored procedure that deletes some rows from a database table. I need to copy data to a text file before the delete operation, in order to check what has been deleted - how do I do that?

My code:

```
DELETE FROM Document
WHERE DocumentID IN (SELECT DISTINCT m.MemberID
                     FROM Member m
                     LEFT JOIN 
                         (SELECT 
                              *,  
                              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY memberid ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
                          FROM Insurance) x ON m.MemberID = x.MemberID AND x.rn = 1
                     WHERE 
                         ((x.id IS NULL AND m.LastChangedDateTime < '2019-10-01') 
                          OR x.ResignationDate < '2019-10-01'));
```

Comment: to be safe use a temporary table then to text file if need be. drop temp table when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

With SQLCMD you could use the following approach:

1. Save your SELECT query in a sql file, we are going to call it "myquery.sql". The query would look almost identical to your DELETE query, with the only difference that we would be using a SELECT clause, instead of DELETE:

```
SELECT FROM Document WHERE...
```

2. Use the following SQLCMD command to execute your query and export the output to a TXT file:

```
sqlcmd -i c:\sql\myquery.sql -o c:\sql\myoutput.txt
```

3. Proceed to delete your rows. Optionally, you can duplicate steps 1 and 2 for the DELETE operation, so you can create one SQL file for the SELECT operation, and a second one for the DELETE operation.

The execution of the sqlcmd commands can be done through a CmdExec job. Just [create a job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-cmdexec-job-step?view=sql-server-ver15) with a step of Type "Operating system" (CmdExec) and type you sqlcmd command in that, then from the stored procedure execute [sp_start_job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-start-job-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) to start that job.

Comment: @Oliver López Ch The stored procedure will be called as a function in an application, how would it be possible to use the sqlcmd in that case?

Comment: I just updated my answer with additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bcp to copy out the table data to a file. You can also use bcp to copy the data in to the table from the data file.

Comment: Would you please provide an example? or at least reference to an example that I can look at? I would like to accept you answer if I get some valuable reference

Comment: @Mindan bcp tablename out filename -U username -P password -S servername -D (if DSN) -c or -n. Check for full bcp documentation at microsoft.com.